# asp Dropdownlist multiple item selection

Tags: asp.net, dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to select multiple items from a drowpdownlist, I'm using bootstrap, but my problem:
I can just get only the first selected item, cannot get others selected ones.

my code (styles and scripts):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" /> <!-- Bootstrap v4.4.1 -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap-select.css" /> <!-- Bootstrap-select v1.13.1 -->
 <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script> <!-- Bootstrap-select v1.13.1  -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('select').selectpicker();
 </script>
```

my DDL:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="selectpicker" ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" multiple data-live-search="true"  SelectionMode="multiple">
            <asp:ListItem>Brasil</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Colombia</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>United States</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Frannce</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Italy</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Japan</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

I use a button and this is OnClick command:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItems = "";
    foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            selectedItems += item.Text + "\\n";
        }
    }
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + selectedItems + "');", true);
}
```

As I said.. I can get only the first item, anyone please can help me?
thanks

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DropDownList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.8)

> allows the user to select a single item from a drop-down list

A [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox?view=netframework-4.8) allows you to select multiple items:

```
<asp:ListBox CssClass="selectpicker" 
             ID="DropDownList1" 
             runat="server" 
             data-live-search="true"  
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem>Brasil</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Colombia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>United States</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Frannce</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Italy</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Japan</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

The rest of your code should work as is, maybe update the ID. [Aspsnippets](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx) have an example using bootstrap.

Comment: Or an asp:CheckBoxList